# Как настроить проект VSC++2013 в соответствии с параметрами make файла

Tags: visual-studio, dll, makefile, lib

Команда **nmake** формирует следующие строки для компилятора(*это не все строки но эти относятся к С++ примеру, есть еще другие, но они для других примеров*)

> cl /nologo /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oy- /D _EXTERNAL_RELEASE /D WIN32 /D
>   NDEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _WINDOWS /D ASYNC_COMMANDS /Gm- /EHsc /GS
>   /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Gd /analyze- /arch:SSE2 
>   /D_NO_OMP_ /MD /D _WINDOWS  /Foexample.obj /nologo /MD -I..\src\api
>   -I..\src\api\c++ ..\examples\c++\example.cpp 
>  example.cpp
>           cl /Fecpp_example.exe /nologo /MD example.obj  libz3.lib /link /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /INCREMENTAL:NO /STACK:8388608
>   /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT

в итоге

> Z3 examples were successfully built.

И в каталоге появляется 3 файла cpp_example.exe, example.obj, cpp_example.pdb(*вернее файлов больше но там для других языков, мне интересно только С++*). 
Работа cpp_example.exe, никак не зависит от example.obj, cpp_example.pdb, то есть, может и зависит но без них прекрасно запускается
При попытке создать консольный проект в VSС++2013 на основе example.cpp

```
#include<vector>
#include"z3++.h"

using namespace z3;

void demorgan() {
    std::cout << "de-Morgan example\n";

    context c;

    expr x = c.bool_const("x");
    expr y = c.bool_const("y");
    expr conjecture = (!(x && y)) == (!x || !y);

    solver s(c);
    // adding the negation of the conjecture as a constraint.
    s.add(!conjecture);
    std::cout << s << "\n";
    std::cout << s.to_smt2() << "\n";
    switch (s.check()) {
    case unsat:   std::cout << "de-Morgan is valid\n"; break;
    case sat:     std::cout << "de-Morgan is not valid\n"; break;
    case unknown: std::cout << "unknown\n"; break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    demorgan();
    return 0;
}
```

Выдает кучи ошибок:
Ошибка  1   error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_Z3_ast_vector_dec_ref"
...
Ошибка  35  error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов:34

Вопрос как настроить проект в соответствии со строкой формируемой nmake?

Comment: Вопрос о импорте настроек проекта из nmake файла остается открытым)

Comment: тогда удалите свой комментарий с текстом «всё решилось само собой». возможно, и вопрос стоит подсократить (нажав [edit]).